# WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips not working on Server

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips is working fine in localhost but not working on server hosting. It's showing any fatal error

```
 Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 36175872) (tried to allocate 133061 bytes) in /homepages/18/d323269449/htdocs/test.addpronetwork.com/flexotech-eCommerce/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/lib/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php on line 2157
```

How to solve this one ?

I already defined the following limits in my site.

```
memory_limit = 512M; 
max_execution_time =3000;
upload_max_filesize = 512M;
post_max_size = 512M;
max_input_vars = 10000;
```